# Why is parsing whitespace-delimited statements slow?

Tags: antlr4

I have a simple ANTLR4 grammar as follows:

```
grammar Foo;

block
    :   statement+
    ;

statement
    :   expression
    ;

expression
    :   literal
    |   op=('+' | '-') expression
    |   expression op=('*' | '/' | '%') expression
    |   expression op=('-' | '+') expression
    ;

literal
    :   NUM
    ;

NUM
    :   INT+
    |   INT* '.' INT+
    ;

fragment
INT
    :   ('0'..'9')+
    ;

WS
    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' ) -> skip
    ;
```

When I use this grammar to parse e.g. "-1 + -84 - -2 * -1 / -2 * -1 - 1 + 1 / -1" as a block using a parser generated for JavaScript, it's extremely slow (on the order of 500ms, and far longer for bigger expressions).  On the other hand, when I parse it as an expression, it parses in about a millisecond.  Finally, if I modify the grammar so that statements are delimited by semicolons, parsing the above input (with a semicolon added to the end) as a block takes about a millisecond.

Is there a way I can structure this grammar so that statements are whitespace delimited and also ensure that blocks of statements such as the above parse quickly?

Comment: Your example block reads as a single statement to me. If it's not then where are the statement boundaries?

Comment: What happens if you "anchor" your `block` rule with the `EOF` token: `block
    :   statement+ EOF
    ;` ?

Comment: It's been a while since I did anything with antlr so pardon me if I'm wrong here but it seems that block is simply one or more statements, and statement is just a statementExpression and statementExpression is just an expression so block is effectively just one or more expressions.  Given that expressions are recursively defined, could it be that you are ending up with an factorial complexity operation?  That is each subset of expressions is being evaluated as a statement until it finds the largest set.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Correct, it can be parsed directly as an expression, or as a statement containing a single expression, or as a block containing a single statement containing a single expression.

Comment: @BartKiers: That didn't make a difference, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Yes, I suspect something like that is happening.  The question is how to structure the grammar so that the parser quickly arrives at a "greedy" parse, i.e. one big expression instead of a sequence of smaller ones.  As it stands, it always gives that answer, it just takes a long time to do it.

Comment: It seems like you are planning on adding some more to the language. Otherwise, you wouldn't need the block or statement, right?  Are you going to add more to the definition of statement because I expect that when you do, it will be have more like it does with the semi-colon.  Right now, your definition of block is essentially the same as expression (you can verify this by removing the +, it should still parse.)  I think that's the root of your issue.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Yes, the above grammar is actually a stripped-down version of the one I'm using, since I wanted to keep the question focused.  The real grammar has several other statement types.  Anyway, imagine I want both "1 + 1" (a block with a single statement/expression) and "1 + 1 2 + 2" (a block with two statements/expressions) to parse.

Comment: I take it then that it's still slow even with the other statement types?

Comment: I've got to run but you might play around with using ? after + to see how that affects things.  It seems unintuitive that this would make it work but I think there's something about the interaction of the statement+ and the expression here.

Comment: One more thing.  I saw something about how ignoring whitespace caused some unexpected changes to greediness.  You might want to try including the ws in the definition of expression instead of ignoring it.